# Como concatenar os registros de duas colunas?

Tags: mysql, funções

Digamos que eu tenha uma tabela com duas colunas nome e sobrenome, por exemplo:

```
Nome   | Sobrenome
-------+-----------
João   | Silva
Mike   | Corin
Carlos | Rodrigues
```

E eu quero unir a coluna do nome com o sobrenome, a ficar o nome completo:

```
Nome
-----------------
João Silva
Mike Corin
Carlos Rodrigues
```

Como eu posso fazer isso? Sem que seja manualmente, talvez com uma função porque já tem milhões de registros e fazer essa tarefa manualmente irá demorar demais.

Comment: vai criar uma coluna nova na tabela ou simplesmente no select ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de tudo, faça **backup** do seu banco de dados e das informações relacionadas a ele. Às vezes alterações muito grandes [**podem** *crashar* o navegador](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/crashing.html).

---

A função para concatenar as tuplas no banco de dados é a [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). Ela retorna a sequência que resulta da concatenação dos argumentos, sendo que pode ter um ou mais argumentos.

Nesse seu caso, para concatenar os valores da coluna `nome` e `sobrenome`, basta executar o seguinte código:

```
UPDATE tabela set nome = concat(nome, " ", sobrenome);
```

Adianto que tomei a liberdade de adicionar um espaço em branco (`" "`), para que fosse  adicionando um espaço entre a concatenação. Se você não quiser basta executar esta *query* ao invés da primeira:

```
UPDATE tabela set nome = concat(nome, sobrenome);
```

Pode também ver este [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f59a79c/1) que demonstra a maneira de realizar o que você quer.